# In which version of ruby appeared ':' instead '=>'?

Tags: ruby

I mean

```
some: true
```

vs

```
:some => true
```

I have problem with compatibility my Rails version and Ruby version and I have to know in which version appeared only `:` instead `=>`.

I don't know how to find this kind of info by Google.

Comment: I cannot parse your sentences. By the way, what is Googe?

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature introduced into Ruby 1.9:

```
{ example: 'key' }
# => { :example => 'key' }
```

This is similar to how JavaScript and other languages define their dictionary-type structures. The keys generated this way are always Symbol-type.

It's also possible to mix and match:

```
variable = :foo
{ example: 'key', 'string' => 'stored', variable => 'thing' }
# => {:example=>"key", "string"=>"stored", :foo=>"thing"}
```

This is a good thing because the `x:` approach is more limited. If you want dots in your keys, for example, you'll need to use the older style.